Discovery On A Pro Athlete's Medical Files By New Team
We see so often in pro sports how a high quality player is transferred to another team and some time later it emerges that this player has a chronic condition affecting their performance - the same injury that put off the selling team from offering them a new contract.
In plain language, the new team were sold a lame horse.
Obviously, the new team spent a day or two making their own medical examination before agreeing the transfer and signing off on the multi-million fee involved. Yet, without really knowing the nature of any physiological weaknesses, it would be well-nigh impossible for a new set of specialists to find a flaw in an otherwise 100% healthy elite athlete.
Is the caveat emptor principle with property also the situation with pro sportsman transfer ?
Or does the huge scale of investment afford a buying team any measure of "discovery" on the athlete's previous medical history, examinations and specialist opinion ?

I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about NFL rules, which are not the law.

Actually it could also pertain to soccer, basketball and other pro sports. Either way, how do sporting bodies' rules supercede the law of the land unless the latter allow it so ?

If that's really your question, the answer is just that private parties are generally permitted to contractually accept obligations that the law doesn't impose. But if your question is whether professional sports teams have taken on such obligations with respect to disclosing injuries, that's not a question about the law.

@Trunk Arbitration. Leagues require pretty much any dispute be handled by league arbitration, not lawsuits.

In soccer, it seems to be okay to withhold medical records for a player and it's entirely up to the buying club's medical specialists to look for all the likely injuries for that type, age and injury record of player. They often fail to find the flaw and swallow the humbug excuses offered by player and selling club, e.g. more salary, "new challenge", etc.

. . . private parties are generally permitted to contractually accept obligations that the law doesn't impose. In several arenas contracts must be fair to the accepting party. Insurance and investment products for example cannot claim growth rates as normal simply because some such investments achieve such rates. A barmaid's contract cannot impose an obligation on her to serve beer topless on Friday nights. Isn't it arguable that since consequential losses on hiring a chronically injured player are huge for the buying club that some protection against adverse selection be imposed ?

Why can't the buying club just... look at the players actual performance in their last season? This would exclude all but the most recent injuries. Played great? Buy! Did not play great? Don't!

Many trades or new contracts are contingent on passing a physical.

Played average for himself but still very good compared to others is a possibility. How closely do you need to watch a guy in real game-time to see how he's lost a yard of pace ? Or can anyone judge the mechanical age of his knee and hip joints or how much worthwhile play is left on them ? Some joints age faster than others. Only doctors doing frequent x-rays of a joint could predict likely wear life for a given player.

@Jon Custer All transfers I ever heard of are contingent on passing a thorough medical. But the questions needing answering demand monitoring over a much longer period than 2-3 days. Questions like wear rate in major joints, muscle-tear recovery speed, etc.

The receiving team would have a right to discovery in litigation. If they were, for instance, to sue the selling team for misrepresentation or for a declaration that the contract is void, in this process, they would have a right to all relevant documents in the possession of the selling team.
If by discovery, you mean something less specific (given that you used the word in quotes: "discovery"), then the selling team would only get "discovery" to the extent that they ask for it as a negotiating position or condition of them agreeing to the contract.
Contracts often have conditions precedent or warranties. A contract could have a selling team warrant that they have disclosed all medical information that they are aware of.
A typical warranty in a sports transfer contract would be that the selling club has:

has made a full and honest disclosure to the buying club of the player’s past and current medical history that could in any way affect his health, fitness and/or ability to play professional football

But whether any of the above is actually the case in any given transaction is a factual question.
